# Number of random events over a period of time

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to keep track of the number of random events in a given period of time. The maximum rate at which I can detect an event is once every second and I need to be able to provide the number of events in the past 30 minutes.

My first crack at this algorithm is to have an array which holds will hold the time stamp in seconds. Every time a new event occurs, all time stamps are shifted down and the new event is placed at the front of the array. When the number of events is requested I remove all events greater than 30 minutes then return the resulting count.

```
time_t event_stamps[60 * 30];
unsigned event_count;

void events_put()
{
    time_t new_event_time = SomeCallToGetTheCurrentTimeInSeconds();

    /* Shift values down the array to make space for the new value at index 0 */
    int i;
    for(i = sizeof(event_stamps) / sizeof(event_stamps[0]); --i > 0; )
    {
        event_stamps[i] = event_stamps[i-1];
    }

    event_stamps[0] = new_event_time;

    if(event_count < sizeof(event_stamps) / sizeof(event_stamps[0]))
    {
        event_count++;
    }   
}

uint32_t events_get(void)
{
    time_t systime_s = SomeCallToGetTheCurrentTimeInSeconds();

    /* Remove elements in the array that are occurred greater than 30 minutes ago */
    int i;
    for(i = event_count; --i >= 0; )
    {
        /* Events arrive in order so events further away in time occur at higher array
         * indices. Therefore, once an event is reached that is sooner than the cutoff
         * time (30 minutes * 60 seconds), there are no more events to remove */
        if(systime_s - event_stamps[i] <= (30 * 60))
        {
            break;
        }

        event_count--;
    }

    return event_count;
}
```

Needless to say, this array is pretty big (60 * 30 = 1800 elements * 4 = 7200 B) and does not fit in my small processor. Is there a way I can keep track of these events without using so much data space?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use a ring buffer, than keep shifting the array content?

Comment: Do you need to track only the number of events in the span on 1800 seconds?

Comment: @2501 Yes, only the number of events in the last 1800 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use a circular bit array indexed by seconds: 1800 bits for 30 seconds.

Keep a record of the last event time.

Set the appropriate bit and record the time when an event occurs, but first clear all bits between the previous event time and now.

When reporting the number of events, first clear all bits between the previous event time and now, then count the bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to hold the history for the last 30 minutes (1800 seconds), and you can only have one event per second, then you only need one bit per event, so use a bit-field. The index of each bit represents an offset in seconds from the current time.

Repeat in a loop each second:
The whole field is shifted one bit to the right. The last bit, which represents the events 1800 seconds ago, is dropped from the array. If it was one, decrement the event counter. Check if an event happened this second, if it did, the bit at the index 0, is set to one, and increment the event counter. (Instead of shifting the whole array, an additional index variable can be used that represents the time offset of 0.)

Additional memory improvement can be achieved using [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), if there are either few events, or few non-events.